# Audit.EntityFramework.Core 16.2.1 not tracking Foreign Object changes

Tags: audit.net

In `POST request` we sent a payload with its Foreign object data and audit GetEntityFrameworkEvent() show correct values.
But when we make a PUT request then `Audit.EntityFramework.Core 16.2.1` does not track Foreign Object changes i.e `Changes Array Field` has same values in every `New` and `Old` fields.

Answer (score 2):

That coould be because of the nature of the update operation.

If you don't explicitly retrieve the object before the update, there is no way for the EF ChangeTracker to know the previous values.

Please check https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/53